ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of null, js engine: hermes
I have upgraded my react native app from version 0.71.10 to 0.72.14.
But i'm not able to use the react-native-picker-module when i click app crashes with  ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of null, js engine: hermes.
Note: This issue is only in Android.
react-native-picker-module verison 2.0.4
[]
Tried upgrading picker module to latest version but still same issue.It's working fine on iOS.

check your picker ref object for handle this error you can use this code
this.pickerRef.current?.show?.()

please before use this  code check your ref object

That only helped to prevent the error, still the picker is not showing.
